# For what real constant $A$, $f(x$) is a continuous function?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

$f(x) = \lfloor x \rfloor *\cos(Ax)$

I got to the result that $ n*(\cos((n+1)*A) = (n+1)*\cos((n+1)*A)$,

so $\cos((n+1)*A) = 0$

so $(n+1)A = (2k+1)*\frac{pi}{2}$

but I can't see what is next.
I will appreciate any help.

Comment: Does "$*$" represent ordinary multiplication?

Comment: yes, it is ordinary multiplication

Comment: This function will be discontinuous at $x=0$ no matter what $A$ is, right? Consider the left-hand and right-hand limits separately.

Comment: Yes, I guess you are right but I am not sure

Comment: Specifically: $$f(-\epsilon) = \lfloor -\epsilon\rfloor\cos (-A\epsilon) = -\cos A\epsilon\to -1$$
$$f(\epsilon) = \lfloor \epsilon \rfloor\cos A\epsilon = 0\cos A\epsilon = 0\to 0$$ so the left and right limits are different